# Add ale fixer for a specific file name?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to define a fixer for `tox.ini` files that invokes [`tox-ini-fmt`](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-ini-fmt), but when defining my fixer mapping, doing the naïve thing of specifying "tox.ini" doesn't work:

```
let g:ale_fixers = {"tox.ini": "tox-ini-fmt"}
```

I have worked around this by defining a custom file type `toxini`, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to do this, since I'm not sure I need to maintain a custom file type just for this.

Comment: "Maintain a custom file type" is a bit of an exaggeration. A custom filetype is like one line of vimscript that will probably never change so there is not much to maintain. The filetype way is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this in `vimrc` or (probably better) `after/filetype.vim`?

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead tox.ini let b:ale_fixers = ["tox-ini-fmt"]
```

Whenever you create a new file or read an existing file called tox.ini, that will set the buffer-local variable `b:ale_fixers` to `["tox-ini-fmt"]`

References:

```
:help :autocmd
:help BufNewFile
:help BufRead
:help buffer-variable
```

and

https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#2ii-fixing